# Function in controller/other file

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new and actually I'm learning working with node.js and expressjs.

When I put all of this code in my app.js all is working correctly, but I want to create this function in controllers/Home directory.

```
    function run() {
        console.log("Hello World.");
    };

    app.all('/hi', function(req, res, next) {
        run();
    });
```

I tried to put this...

```
var Home = require('./controllers/Home');
    app.all('/hi', function(req, res, next) {
        Home.run();
    });
```

...and paste the function code into Home.js but it doesn't working.

Can you explain me this?
Regards.

Comment: The last `;` at the end of the `run()` function doesn't seem ok, delete it and try again.

Comment: @dburner, I tried it but it have still error 'TypeError: Home.run is not a function'

Comment: Home is a directory or a file?

Comment: @AtulAgrawal controllers/Home.js

Comment: I'm totally new at node.js, if my method to do this is wrong can you explain me how to make it correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please export this function from your Home file like this

```
module.exports.run = function run(){
console.log('run');
```

}

and then try

Comment: I tried, still 'TypeError: Home.run is not a function'.

Comment: thanks a lot for your work, not I understand it. Regards!

Answer (score -1):

So the `run()` function is in another file than where `var Home = require(..)` is? Then you need to export your run function. So in your first file where `run` is defined you write

`module.exports.run = run;`

Comment: No no, function run is in controllers/Home.js and var Home is the same (var Home = require('./controllers/Home');).